# JavaScript, PHP - Error message using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar

We have a web application that uses FullCalendar and we have to show 2 types of errors to the user on a certain page. First is *"Please settle your previous transaction"* and the second one *"Schedule is already taken, please refresh the browser"*.

The issue is that I can only do one and I can't seem to figure out how to work it out with condition statements. Here's what I have so far:

***courts.php***

```
select: function(start, end) {

        if(start.isBefore()) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            swal("Invalid time slot", "Selected time has already passed", "error");
            return false;
        }
    
     var id = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
     var email = '<?php echo $reservee; ?>';
     var d = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "MMM DD @",);
     var t1 = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "h:mm a",);
     var t2 = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "hh:mm a",);
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",);
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: `You selected ${d} ${t1} to ${t2}`,
        icon: "info",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: false,
      })
      .then((insert) => {
        if (insert) {
          $.ajax({
             url:"insert.php",
              type:"POST",
              data:{id:id, email:email, start:start, end:end},
             error: function() {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php",false);
                xmlhttp.send(null);
                var message = xmlhttp.responseText;
                swal("Oops!", message, "error");
             },
             success:function(){
              calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
              swal("Ready for payment!", "You will now be redirected for payment", "success");
              setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.replace("http://localhost/DunkReserve/myreservations.php");

              }, 2000);
              
             }
          });
        }
      });
    },
```

***insert.php***

```
if(isset($_POST["email"])){

    include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $i = $_POST['id'];
    $s = $_POST['start'];
    $check = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE gymID='$i' AND start_event='$s';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $check);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($resultCheck > 0){
        echo "Schedule already taken. Please refresh your browser.";
        header("location: ../error.php");
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE email = '$email' AND status = '0';";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0){
            echo "Please settle the payment on your previous reservation.";
            header("location: ../error.php");
        }else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO events (gymID, email, start_event, end_event, start_time, expires) VALUES (:gymID, :email, :start_event, :end_event, :start_time, :expires)";
            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute(
                array(
                ':gymID' => $_POST['id'],
                ':email'  => $_POST['email'],
                ':start_event' => $_POST['start'],
                ':end_event' => $_POST['end'],
                ':start_time' => $start_time,
                ':expires' => $end_time
                )
            );
        }
    }   
}
```

**header("location: ../error.php");** is actually only meant to trigger the error and I don't even know what I'm doing. **error.php** does not even exist and there may be other ways to do it.

I am specifically working on the code below (which does not work):

```
error: function() {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php",false);
                xmlhttp.send(null);
                var message = xmlhttp.responseText;
                swal("Oops!", message, "error");
             },
```

Here is how the error message looks like:
[image]

But I can only do this if I manually type the message like:

```
error: function() {
   swal("Oops!", "Please settle the payment on your previous reservation.", "error");
},
```

I know that there's something wrong with my if conditions in insert.php but I don't know what. I honestly do not know what I'm doing at this point and I would appreciate all your response. Also, please don't mind how poorly written the code is and if it is prone to SQL injections.

Comment: What types of errors are you seeing in your browser console? The `header("location: ../error.php");` in your `insert.php` is concerning, as your are redirecting to a script that you say does not exist.

Comment: **Warning:** Your SELECT statements are vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You have parameterised your INSERT statement, but not the SELECTs. You need to protect _all_ your queries.

Comment: Any reason you use $.ajax in one place and then xmlHttpRequest a few lines below? Code is usually more maintainable if it's consistent.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with what you have done, but to show the error properly using JS;

in **courts.php;**

```
       error: function() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php",false);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            var message = xmlhttp.responseText;
            if(message=="taken"){
                  Swal.fire({
                  type: 'error',
                  title: 'Oops...',
                  text: 'Schedule already taken. Please refresh your browser.'
                })}
            else if(message=="settle_payment"){
                      Swal.fire({
                      type: 'error',
                      title: 'Oops...',
                      text: 'Please settle the payment on your previous reservation.'
                    })}
            },
```

in **insert.php;**  make those two echos same as the 'message' in above JS code

```
if($resultCheck > 0){
    echo "taken";
    header("location: ../error.php");
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE email = '$email' AND status = '0';";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0){
        echo "settle_payment";
        header("location: ../error.php");
    }
```